# Get 404 page URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

It is so strange I cannot find a function in the API to get the link to the 404 page link.

I need to check if a page exists return permalink or return 404 page link.

Am I missing something or am I looking in the wrong places?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a native function, so you'll have to set the 404 yourself:

```
function wp_404_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    get_template_part( 404 ); 
    exit();
}
```

Call this function in your `else` block.

Comment: I need the URL to the 404 page. Wouldn't this function return the template for the 404 page?

Comment: Yes, because there is no "url" to the 404 page. It's a template that gets called when wp_query returns a 404 on regular requests. You will have to include the template as part of your conditional block.